# How to add only checked rows in APEX tabular forms to another table?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, sql-insert, oracle-apex

I've created a tabular form from a view - so only the checked items be added to a table. So far I can only insert all the records not individually selected rows.

This is the code I used:

```
DECLARE
   v_insertcount NUMBER := 0;
BEGIN
   FOR i IN 1 .. apex_application.g_f02.COUNT
   LOOP
     IF apex_application.g_f01 (i) IS NOT NULL THEN -- this is the checkbox

       insert into my_table (pme_id, MYREF, STAC, START_DATE)
        values ( SEQ_PME.NEXTVAL,
                 :P5_MYREF
                 apex_application.g_f02(i),
                 apex_application.g_f03(i)
               )

       v_insertcount := v_insertcount + 1;
     END IF;
   END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: For sake of clarity, does the code given in your question really *add all the records*, regardless if the checkbox is checked or not ?

Comment: hi...no it doesn't...only when its all checked does it do the insert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to remember that [only checked checkboxes are submitted](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17556_01/doc/apirefs.40/e15519/apex_app.htm#CHDGJBAB). So you cannot test for `NULL` in order to identify *unchecked* boxes. That are simply *not* in the array.

So, as the checkbox array size is lower or equal to the other fields array size, you cannot use *index* to find corresponding values of the same row.

There are some [clever tricks to overcome that limitations](http://www.inside-oracle-apex.com/checkboxes-in-tabular-forms-the-easy-way/). However, for simple cases, a solution is simply to use a look-up function to map `id` to *index*.

```
   FUNCTION array_search(value IN VARCHAR2, arr IN apex_application_global.vc_arr2)
   RETURN PLS_INTEGER
   IS
   BEGIN
     FOR i IN 1 .. arr.COUNT
     LOOP
       IF arr(i) = value THEN
         RETURN i;
       END IF;
     END LOOP;

     return 0;
   END;
```

This is a linear search. So the performances are *not* very good. Anyway for form processing it is probably sufficient. Given that function, you can now write:

> <sub>Region source</sub>
>
> ```
> SELECT APEX_ITEM.CHECKBOX(1,pme_id) " ",
>        ...
> ```

> <sub>*on-submit* process</sub>
>
> ```
>    FOR i IN 1 .. apex_application.g_f01.COUNT -- your checkboxes
>    LOOP
>      -- identify the "row index"
>      idx := array_search(apex_application.g_f01(i), apex_application.g_f02);
>      --                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
>      --                     checkboxes array               id array
>
>      -- assuming now idx > 0
>      -- (in production code, should check and log in case of `0`)
>
>
>      -- do whatever you want, using `idx` as index
>
>      insert into my_table 
>                    (pme_id, 
>                     MYREF,
>                     STAC,
>                     START_DATE
>                                 ) 
>       values ( 
>                       SEQ_PME.NEXTVAL,
>                       :P5_MYREF
>                       apex_application.g_f02 (idx),
>                        apex_application.g_f03 (idx)
>                    );
>
>    END LOOP;
> ```